# Magento send Custom email

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, transactional-mail

I am using Custom order status While changing it send a mail. It's working fine

```
public function shipementorderAction(){
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
                $order->setData('state', 'shipement');
                $order->setStatus('shipement');
                $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                $order->save(); 

                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);

                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );
                //$this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/index');
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully'); $this->_redirectReferer();


                }
```

I used this to send a mail

```
**$order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);**
```

How to send custom email template(New Template) per status

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method as starting point:

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php::queueNewOrderEmail()

```
public function queueNewOrderEmail($forceMode = false)
{
    $storeId = $this->getStore()->getId();

    if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewOrderEmail($storeId)) {
        return $this;
    }

    // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
    $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
    $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);

    // Start store emulation process
    /** @var $appEmulation Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation */
    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

    try {
        // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
        $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($this->getPayment())
            ->setIsSecureMode(true);
        $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
        $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
        throw $exception;
    }

    // Stop store emulation process
    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

    // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
    if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
    }

    /** @var $mailer Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer */
    $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
    /** @var $emailInfo Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info */
    $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
    $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
        // Add bcc to customer email
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
        }
    }
    $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

    // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy'
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'copy') {
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($email);
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }
    }

    // Set all required params and send emails
    $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
    $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
    $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
        'order'        => $this,
        'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
        'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
    ));

    /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
    $emailQueue = Mage::getModel('core/email_queue');
    $emailQueue->setEntityId($this->getId())
        ->setEntityType(self::ENTITY)
        ->setEventType(self::EMAIL_EVENT_NAME_NEW_ORDER)
        ->setIsForceCheck(!$forceMode);

    $mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();

    $this->setEmailSent(true);
    $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'email_sent');

    return $this;
}
```

Obviously you have to implement some methods to retrieve configuration like $storeId and $templateId that in the example are already there (since is declared inside the order model).

I think that the best approach could be hook the order status change and implement all the email send logic in a helper in order be reused in the future and even better split that method and abstract all the order logic, so you will have a good base to send any kind of emails.

I assume that you already know how to save and load configuration but i recommend you to use some method `(like getEmailTemplateByStatus($status))` with a default return value to avoid errors just if someone add a custom status and it hasn't any template mapped.

Hope it help

Comment: @ MauroNigrele 
Hi, Do you know about html to magento conversion?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara sorry i don't catch your point

Comment: Okay i'll tell you.

Comment: i want to convert html to magento . I have html pages, from that i want to make magento website. I think you got .Please tell me

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara I don't understand what you need and i'm afraid that a question inside an answer comment isn't the right place to discuss another topic, and isn't useful for anyone with your same concerns too, so can you create a question well detailed and leave the link here? thanks

Comment: Ok i agree.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68856/how-to-convert-html-to-magento

Comment: The question you linked it's closed, anyway it's an biz question you can't just translform html files into magento you must create a theme declare layouts and edit templates to achieve it. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom email send, see answer of this question

```
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122837/custom-email-template-not-working
```

instead of

```
**$order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);**
```