# Custom Email template not working

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, transactional-mail

I am not getting Custom email template if i use simple mail function i got a mail what mistake i made here
**observer.php**

```
 class Manoj_Test_Model_Observer {


    public function successAfter($observer){




    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                ->loadDefault('my_custom_email');               
$emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $iDefaultStoreId));
$emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')); 
$subject=$this->__(' test cubject');
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject($subject);  
$emailTemplateVariables = array();         
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
$emailTemplate->send('manojpanneer98@gmail.com','test test', $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);



    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Manoj_Test>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Manoj_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <test>
                <class>Manoj_Test_Model</class>
            </test>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <test>
                <class>Manoj_Test_Block</class>
            </test>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <test>
                <class>Manoj_Test_Helper</class>
            </test>
        </helpers>

        <template>
            <email>

                <my_custom_email>
                    <label>Custom email</label>
                    <file>my_custom_email.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </my_custom_email>
            </email>
        </template>
        <events>


             <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <marketplace>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>test/observer</class>
                        <method>successAfter</method>
                    </marketplace>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        </events>




    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Manoj_Test</module>
                    <frontName>Test</frontName>
                </args>
            </test>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

my_custom_email.html file path : `app/locale/en_US/template/email/my_custom_email.html`

```
<!--@subject My custom email template @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt",
"var data.custom_variable":"Custom variable"}
@-->

<!--@styles
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
@-->

<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                    <!-- [ header starts here] -->
                    <table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                        <!-- [ Header starts here] -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <a href="{{store url=""}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" border="0"/></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- [ Header ends here] -->
                        <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">This is my custom email template</h1>
                                <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 8px 0;"><strong>My custom variable is :</strong> {{var custom_variable}}</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- [middle ends here]-->
                        <!-- [Footer content starts here] -->
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you again, <strong>{{var store.getFrontendName()}}</strong></p></center></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- [Footer content ends here] -->
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You haven't defined $email_template_variables variable in your observer plz check my answer for update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are processing template. you have to processed template to send email.

```
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
$email_template->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables,$storeId=null);
```

working email code

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                ->loadDefault('custom_email');               
$emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $iDefaultStoreId));
$emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')); 
$subject=$this->__(' test cubject');
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject($subject);  
$emailTemplateVariables = array();         
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
$emailTemplate->send('test@test.com','test test', $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);
```

Comment: got error www.domain.com is currently unable to handle this request. where i need to add can you please update observer code

Comment: can you please give me working email template code

Comment: added the working template code...

Comment: same no luck got error www.domain.com is currently unable to handle this request. where i need to add can you please update observer code

Comment: did you check in admin the template is loading or not? confirm that first

Comment: Yes it's loading

Comment: did you check the processed template let me give you hint to check this code outside the observer add this code in any phtml file then check his processing then you will able to find the error.

Comment: can you please check my updated question i added my full code

Comment: yes i see that but can do that what i asked?

Comment: sorry idon't know how to add can you plese tell me where i need to add

Comment: can you please tell me how to add and where to add

Comment: i am asking about for testing add any file that you can access so you can see what are error use view.phtml just add code and run

Comment: No error i added view.phtml it's working fine

Comment: email is working?

Comment: Yes I got a mail

Comment: then no code error check your observer method is calling or not

Comment: Yes If i add simple mail function i got a mail but email template only not working

Comment: if this code ins working on view.phtml then must work on Observer too

Comment: can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123222/coupon-code-problem

Comment: @Kothari sorry no idea about that

Comment: Ok thanks ..... i have problem in checkout i can't able to place order any guess

Comment: i check that on order place button the ajax call is looping check there are multiple call on that.

Comment: Hi did you face this type of problem http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136901/magento-magmi-upload-error