# Magento Magmi upload error

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I tried to upload product through magmi. After run import i got an error

[image]

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

How can i fix this

Comment: Does the import fail immediately or partway through the import?

Comment: it's failed means not import single product also

Comment: restart mysql at server and also check your credential in magmi and try again

Comment: I done restart my sql still same error

Comment: If your magento store is working properly then you have entered the database credentials wrong in the magmi profile

Comment: Might be you have one or more space in your db credential please check that and let me know

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is mysql specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897406/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-timed-out-on-my-local-computer

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a local socket then you should specify that you are using a socket under connectivity other wise you will have to add a tcp route such as `localhost` or an ip address such as `127.0.0.1`
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the error because the magmi importer has timed out while uploading data to your database. You can ask your hosting providers to increase the maximum timeout of your sql database and increase maximum memory.